# How is it that Apple is paying no taxes in New Zealand?

Tags: taxation, multinational-companies

Apparently [Apple pays no taxes in New Zealand](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/business/news/article.cfm?c_id=3&objectid=11820240), even though it has employees and profit-making operations there amounting to over a billion dollars per year. The cross linked article does not really explain how it is that they are paying no taxes. What are the relevant rules?

Comment: That article is over a year old, so the position may have changed, but in the past Apple was redirecting its international profits through Ireland twice to reduce taxes.  There is NZ Goods and Services Tax on sales of Apple phones

Comment: @Henry That is not what the article says. The article says it involves some kind of relationship with Australia.

Comment: indeed, so profits from New Zealand were diverted first to Australia, but it used to pay little tax in Australia either [(AUS\$85 million on AUS\$8 billion of profit in one particular year)](https://www.smh.com.au/business/the-economy/apples-85-million-tax-bill-is-a-fraction-of-its-almost-8-billion-revenue-20160126-gmej0z.html).  My guess is that it took advantage a succession of double taxation agreements, such as NZ-AUS and AUS-Ireland

Comment: This might be better suited to Law StackExchange.

Comment: @Henry Please post answers as answers.